# Drools Workbench - Compare common attribute from different objects

Tags: drools, drools-guvnor, drools-flow

Does anyone know how to add a condition on drools workbench for comparing attributes with the same name but from different objects (like their IDs) ?

[Workbench screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsQm2.png)

What I want to add is a 3rd condition like "l.ID = o.ID". If the facts do not have the same ID, it does not print "login". I cannot find a way to do it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Cheers,

Comment: I do not use workbench. Are you able to write code in DRL?

Comment: Yes. But the thing is, our project consists in embedding the workbench in a web application and have the users (who have no technological background) writing the rules themselves.

Nevertheless, workbench allows "Free form DRL" conditions. But even when I write "l.ID = (or ==) o.ID" it gives a syntax error.

Comment: o.getID().equals(I.getID())?

Comment: No, it still fires a syntax error ("mismatched input '.' in rule "test" "). But I've found a possible solution, see the answer below. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a possible solution.

[id match](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BM5K4.png)

You need to bound the "ID" attribute of the 1st object to a variable and then compare the same attribute of the 2nd object ("ID") with the created variable. It was hard to get here because, in the first "WHEN" clause, the GUI is misleading: "--- please choose ---" is not mandatory, and it will only work if no option is selected.

This seems to do trick, but if everyone knows other (i.e., better) solutions. Feel free to post them.

Cheers,